# ServiceFabric / IFabricSecretStoreClient / COM Exception

Tags: azure-service-fabric, visual-studio-2019

I'm not finding much on this, and after spending most of the day...I'm looking for help..

The exception I get is this:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'IFabricSecretStoreClient'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '{38C4C723-3815-49D8-BDF2-68BFB536B8C9}' failed due to the following
>   error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

I'm able to instantiate the proxy to the Stateful Service with this code:

```
var servicekey = new ServicePartitionKey(0);
  var queryserviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/XXXX/xxxxxxxxxx");
  var proxyHandle = ServiceProxy.Create<IAnInterfaceName>(queryserviceUri, servicekey, TargetReplicaSelector.PrimaryReplica);
```

Then I use the proxy:

```
var result = await proxyHandle.OperationOnServiceContract(dataPackage);
```

At this point I get the error...

Stacktrace...

> at System.Fabric.FabricClient.CreateNativeClient(IEnumerable`1
>   connectionStringsLocal)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.<>c__DisplayClass27_0.<WrapNativeSyncInvoke>b__0()
>   at System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke[TResult](Func`1
>   func, String functionTag, String functionArgs)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.WrapNativeSyncInvoke(Action action,
>   String functionTag, String functionArgs)    at
>   System.Fabric.Interop.Utility.RunInMTA(Action action)    at
>   System.Fabric.FabricClient.InitializeFabricClient(SecurityCredentials
>   credentialArg, FabricClientSettings newSettings, String[]
>   hostEndpointsArg)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Client.ServicePartitionResolver.<>c.b__21_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Client.ServicePartitionResolver.GetClient()
>   at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Client.ServicePartitionResolver.ResolveHelperAsync(Func`5
>   resolveFunc, ResolvedServicePartition previousRsp, TimeSpan
>   resolveTimeout, TimeSpan maxRetryInterval, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Uri serviceUri)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.CommunicationClientFactoryBase`1.GetClientAsync(Uri
>   serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey, TargetReplicaSelector
>   targetReplicaSelector, String listenerName, OperationRetrySettings
>   retrySettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.FabricTransport.Client.FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory.GetClientAsync(Uri
>   serviceUri, ServicePartitionKey partitionKey, TargetReplicaSelector
>   targetReplicaSelector, String listenerName, OperationRetrySettings
>   retrySettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.GetCommunicationClientAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1.InvokeWithRetryAsync[TResult](Func`2
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Type[]
>   doNotRetryExceptionTypes)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.V2.Client.ServiceRemotingPartitionClient.InvokeAsync(IServiceRemotingRequestMessage
>   remotingRequestMessage, String methodName, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.InvokeAsyncV2(Int32
>   interfaceId, Int32 methodId, String methodName,
>   IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody requestMsgBodyValue,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Builder.ProxyBase.ContinueWithResultV2[TRetval](Int32
>   interfaceId, Int32 methodId, Task`1 task)    at
>   XXXXWeb.Controllers.XXXController.OperationOnServiceContract(XXXRequest
>   xxxRequest) in
>   C:\Users\codputer\Source\Repos\xxxxxx\xxxx.Web\Controllers\XXXController.cs:line
>   44

oh I'm using this for a listener:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
{
  return this.CreateServiceRemotingReplicaListeners();
}
```

Comment: Can you specify in your question:  the version of the SDK and Runtime, where these services are being used? Where is the Client hosted, what type is the client, where is the Service being called hosted!

Comment: this seems to be the same error message: 
https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/476

the solution is to upgrade

Comment: Yes, is very likely, just wanted to confirm the version before answering anything, many people having this issue lately [#1374@Azure/service-fabric-issues](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1374) and [#262@Microsoft/service-fabric](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric/issues/262)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted on these issues:

- [#476@Azure/service-fabric-issues](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/476)
- [#1374@Azure/service-fabric-issues](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/1374)
- [#262@Microsoft/service-fabric](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric/issues/262)

These COM issues happens whenever you use newer Nuget packages targeting older version of service fabric runtime, this kind of error occurs.

**You should always use the packages targeted to the same version of your cluster runtime**, on last case, use package older than the cluster version.

Comment: Would really like a better error... i understand why the error mentions COM interfaces .... but how many people understand that COM is still way down under the covers of the servicefabric remoting?  In all that vodoo magic under the covers can't there be an interface where in runtime this is checked, and throw an exception - interfaces are mismatched - upgrade your version!